# Finding an item within a list within another list?

Tags: c#, .net, list, collections

Okay, so let's say I have a `List<car>`. Each car also contains a `List<part>`. Each part has an `ID` associated with it. I'm only given the `ID` to a `part`, and I want to find the `car` that contains that `part`. What is the best way to find this `car`?

Comment: Do you want to find the first car or all cars with that part?

Comment: @Nogwater Each part has a unique identifier across all cars so there will be only one car with that part

Answer (score 17, accepted):

How about with LINQ?

```
List<Car> cars = ...
var carToFind = cars.FirstOrDefault(car => car.Parts.Any(part => part.Id == idToFind));
```

In English: "Find the first car (or null if no such car exists) that has any part with an Id matching the desired Id."

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, then did `ToArray()` because I couldn't think of using `Any`.

Answer (score 5):

```
var id = 123;
var cars = new List<Car>();
var theCar = cars.Single(
          car => car.parts
                    .FirstOrDefault(part => part.Id == id) != null
          );
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if there is more than one car found. You might want to remove the Single() call. Also, Contains would not work in this situation (unless you implemented your own version).

Comment: @Guvante the error here is 'Cannot resolve method Contains(int), candidates are Contains(part).

Comment: Part is an object, and you're passing an Int to Contains. You should create and Part, and assign the Id with the IdToSearch. but I'm not sure if Contains compare all attributes, and don't know how many attributes got each Part

Comment: @jsmith: That was intentional, "Each part has a unique identifier across all cars so there will be only one car with that part", if the design calls for unique, no reason to be ambiguous with it.

Comment: @proseidon: Sorry, for some reason I thought you were storing part ids.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a LINQ query like this:

```
// List<car> cars;
int id = 101;
var result = Cars.Where (c => c.parts.Where (p => p.ID == id).Any ());
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
foreach(Car car in listOfCars)
{
    if (car.parts.Contains(partID))
    {
        return car;
    }
}
```

**Edit2:** Ah, I misunderstood and thought that your car had a list of partIDs.

So, in that case...

```
foreach(Car car in listOfCars)
{
    foreach(Part part in car.parts)
    {
        if (part.id == partId)
        {
            return car;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit1:** Depending on your use case, it might also make sense to maintain an "index" that maps from part IDs to cars.  Something like:

```
var partIDToCar = Dictionary<string, Car>();
```

As you are putting parts in your cars, you update your index:

```
partIDToCar[partID] = car;
```

Then, it's a quick check to get the car:

```
if (partIDToCar.ContainsKey(partID))
{
    return partIDToCar[partID];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work as .Contains expects the type part as opposed to an attribute in a part

Answer (score 1):

Find within a Find

```
List<car> cars = new List<Car>();
List<car> carWithParts = cars.Find(x => x.parts.Any(y => y.PartID=123));
```

This will work if multiple cars could contain the same PartID.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var thePart;

 foreach (var part in list<parts>)
 {
 if (part.id = ID)
 thePart = part;
 }

 foreach (var car in list<cars>)
 {
 if (car.Part = thePart)
 return car;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot directly access parts - I have to go through cars.